# How to stop button from moving after bigger items appear on top

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I made a simple quote generator and my button moves up and down depending on the length of the quote. How do I stop that?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmatias/cmdk0w7o/2/)

```
  .btn {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #3949AB;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: .15em;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #3949AB;
    color: #fff;
    border-style: inset;
  }
}
```

Something I also realized when I put my code in fiddle is that the background image wasn't filling the background completely on the more intricate small sizes after the button is clicked. How is that possible? I have viewport to 100.

Comment: If you want the button not to move due to the texts then what should be the output? either you can fix a container for the text so that button will be placed prior.

Comment: I have added my answer you can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just add fixed height to the container:

```
#quoteDisplay {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #5C6BC0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em 0;
  height: 90px;
}
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var quotes = [
  "A man who stands for nothing will fall for anything.", "We are nonviolent with people who are nonviolent with us.", "Don\’t be in a hurry to condemn because he doesn\’t do what you do or think as you think or as fast. There was a time when you didn\’t know what you know today.", "My alma mater was books, a good library… I could spend the rest of my life reading, just satisfying my curiosity", "There is no better than adversity. Every defeat, every heartbreak, every loss, contains its own seed, its own lesson on how to improve your performance next time.", "A race of people is like an individual man; until it uses its own talent, takes pride in its own history, expresses its own culture, affirms its own selfhood, it can never fulfill itself.", "I for one believe that if you give people a thorough understanding of what confronts them and the basic causes that produce it, they’ll create their own program, and when the people create a program, you get action.", "Without education, you’re not going anywhere in this world.", "You don’t have to be a man to fight for freedom. All you have to do is to be an intelligent human being.", "I feel like a man who has been asleep somewhat and under someone else’s control. I feel that what I’m thinking and saying is now for myself. Before it was for and by the guidance of Elijah Muhammad. Now I think with my own mind, sir!"
];
function newQuote(){
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.nav-items {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#c9df8a, #f0f7da);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #3949AB;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: .15em;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #3949AB;
    color: #fff;
    border-style: inset;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 7rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #3949AB;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#quoteDisplay {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #5C6BC0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em 0;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Malcom X Quote Generator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Malcom X Quote Generator</h1>
    <img src="img/gadg.png" alt="">
      <div id="quoteDisplay">
      </div>
      <button class="btn" type="button" onClick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>
    </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I mean:

```js
var quotes = [
  "A man who stands for nothing will fall for anything.", "We are nonviolent with people who are nonviolent with us.", "Don\’t be in a hurry to condemn because he doesn\’t do what you do or think as you think or as fast. There was a time when you didn\’t know what you know today.", "My alma mater was books, a good library… I could spend the rest of my life reading, just satisfying my curiosity", "There is no better than adversity. Every defeat, every heartbreak, every loss, contains its own seed, its own lesson on how to improve your performance next time.", "A race of people is like an individual man; until it uses its own talent, takes pride in its own history, expresses its own culture, affirms its own selfhood, it can never fulfill itself.", "I for one believe that if you give people a thorough understanding of what confronts them and the basic causes that produce it, they’ll create their own program, and when the people create a program, you get action.", "Without education, you’re not going anywhere in this world.", "You don’t have to be a man to fight for freedom. All you have to do is to be an intelligent human being.", "I feel like a man who has been asleep somewhat and under someone else’s control. I feel that what I’m thinking and saying is now for myself. Before it was for and by the guidance of Elijah Muhammad. Now I think with my own mind, sir!"
];

function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.nav-items {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#c9df8a, #f0f7da);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #3949AB;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: .15em;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #3949AB;
    color: #fff;
    border-style: inset;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 7rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #3949AB;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#quoteDisplay {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #5C6BC0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em 0;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Malcom X Quote Generator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Malcom X Quote Generator</h1>
    <img src="img/gadg.png" alt="">
    <div id="quoteDisplay">
    </div>
    <button class="btn" type="button" onClick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you have your quotes appearing, just wrap them inside a div and you can set the margin of the button towards the container of the quotes instead of the quotes themselves.

For example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <h1>The quote goes here</h1>
</div>
<button></button>
```

This way, you can set a height on css for the 'wrapper' and the margin-top for the 'button', this should do the trick.